# How to provide size for BAMaxInstallSize in BackgroundAssets?

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc, background-assets-framework

As mentioned in apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/bamaxinstallsize) BAMaxInstallSize is sum of bundle size and assets that download immediately after app installation.

I have to download a video using background asset and it is non-essential type asset.The asset size is 15,53,84,552 bytes (168.6 MB on disk). Now the problem is I'm not sure about my app's bundle size and it may vary when I'm adding new feature.

How to provide size here?

I used to provide max size of 3GB. But My app size in app store will shown as 3GB.